# Can I configure low disk space warning to a lesser threshold?

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, notification

Ubuntu 10.10 warns me about low disk space even when there are about 2 GiB free. For me "low disk space" is 50 MiB or less as I use to use my disks at 100% capacity. The warning could be useful for me if it was warning only when I am really running nearly OUT of space. Can this be configured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notification is part of the gnome-settings-daemon, you can change its behaviour in gconf-editor. To do so:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gconf-editor`
2. Go to apps > gnome_settings_daemon > plugins > housekeeping
3. Change `free_size_gb_no_notify` to `0.05` (for ~50MB) or whatever you'd prefer.

There is also a bunch of other settings in there you may find helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately it only accepts integer values, so I can't set it 0.05 - only 1 GB at least.

Comment: If you create the key of type 'Float', you will be able to specify a value of 0.1 (100MB). I was unable to enter lower value, because of the precision limited to 1 decimal digit

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 seems moved to `dconf-editor`

Answer (score 1):

The terminal way, to get the actual GB value:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping free-size-gb-no-notify
```

to set a new GB value of 35

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping free-size-gb-no-notify 35
```

Comment: or using `dconf-editor`, but it is very limited, we cant set a float, I want 500MB (0.5GB) and it is an integer that cant be changed... so annoying...

Answer (score 1):

at ubuntu 18.04, as the precision is still low (GB and not MB), do it yourself (btw, I only get warnings for root FS).

script this and add to startup apps:

```
#/bin/bash

#1st disable system default:
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.housekeeping free-size-gb-no-notify 0

nDelayCheck=30;
nDelayTakeAction=$((nDelayCheck*10));
nLimMB=500;
while true;do 
  nFreeRootMB=$(df / --output=avail -B M |tail -n 1 |tr -d M |awk '{print $1}');
  if((nFreeRootMB<nLimMB));then 
    date;
    declare -p nFreeRootMB;
    notify-send -u critical -t 10 "Local root filesystem available space is too low: ${nFreeRootMB}MB.";
    sleep $nDelayTakeAction;
  fi;
  sleep $nDelayCheck;
done
```